# TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code below is in a component file, it's placed inside the render function of the component. In the main.js, I declared

```
this.state = {
    players: [], //used in another component
    teams = {}
};
```

This is the part of the component code where I'm getting the error.

```
{Object.keys(this.props.teams)
            .map((teamName) => this.props.teams[teamName])
            .sort((teamA, teamB) => {
                return teamA.score < teamB.score;
            })
            .map((team, index) => {
                return(<Component key={index} rank={index + 1} team={team} />);
            })
        }
```

It highlights the first line {Object.keys(this.props.teams) and says cannot convert Undefined to object. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: Are both of these snippets coming from the same component? If so, shouldn't it be `this.state.teams` and not props?

Comment: No the top snippet is from the Main.js, the bottom snippet is inside the render function of the actual component JS file

Comment: Debug. Put a breakpoint on that line. See which of `this`, `props`, or `teams` is undefined...

Comment: Alright, was just asking to make sure. Next question: are you passing the prop down to the component? e.g. `<TeamsComponent teams={this.state.teams} />`

Comment: @Kingdaro Oh wow. I feel retarded, I just had the <TeamsComponent/> and didn't even think to look there. That fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, happens to the best of us ^^ Since it was a simple mistake, don't think there's any need for an answer this time around

Comment: This should be closed as it seems to be caused by a simple typographical error and is unlikely to be of use to future readers.